# Visual Studio 2010 - Warnings only shown for active file

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, warnings

i hope you can help me with my problem in Visual Studio 2010.

Normally in Visual Studio 2008, when i compile a project warnings for all files are shown. But not so in Visual Studio 2010. When i compile a project warnings are shown not until a file is active and then only warnings for the active file are shown in error list.

And I have recently found out something new: the problem only seems to be in ASP.NET Pages (.master, .aspx), but not in Behind-Code-Files (.master.cs, .aspx.cs). Is there a problem with warnings in relation with ASP.NET Pages (except the behind-code-files)?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
HeManNew

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 actually behave the same when listing errors and warnings for pages.

A page's errors and warnings appear in the Error List when its editor is open (regardless of whether it's the active window) or when the *errors* (not *warnings* or *messages*) prevent the application from compiling. But because markup pages are not compiled, only server-side errors prevent the application from compiling.

So, in sum, Visual Studio is behaving correctly. To see the errors and warnings particular to a markup page, you need to open it first. Compiling has nothing to do with markup errors.

Answer (score 1):

I know described behavior since VS2005 (I have no experience with earlier versions).

The `.aspx` is compiled at runtime (or when it is opened in VS 2010). So errors (and warnings) are found when page is run. You can even edit `.aspx` and new version is used when page is reloaded (the load time is considerably longer).

I don't know any way to say to iis to compile all aspx.

But maybe we experience a different behavior because I see warnings for all opened `.aspx` files, not only for the active one.